# Getting error while building docker image

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, dockerfile

My Docker file is

```
FROM python:3
ADD myapp.py /
RUN pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 install pandas
CMD ["python3", "./myapp.py]
```

When I build the docker image using
`docker build -t gaurav .`
I get the following errors

```
Step 4/5 : RUN  pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
 ---> Running in 8f938c75e2e0
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fae543d7cd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fae543d79d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fae543d7220>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fae543d7640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fae543d7790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install tensorflow-gpu' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Can you help me here, I want to install all these packages, but I can't get past these errors.

Comment: I tried changing the order of installation, like installing numpy first, instead of tensorflow-gpu. Still I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33374 - tensorflow is not available for python3.8 so you have to use python image with version 3.7 or lower:

`FROM python:3.7`

Answer (score 0):

As stated here [Tensorflow - requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

> Tensorflow is supported only Python 3.5–3.7